# Is there something like dkpro-lab for python?

Tags: python

I used [dkpro-lab](https://code.google.com/p/dkpro-lab/) a while ago for, well, parameter sweeping experiments in text mining. Right now I am in a python project, and feel the need for something similar. I have looked into luigi, and I guess I could set something similar up with it, but maybe I don't need to reinvent the wheel. Is there already something similar out in the wild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you asked this quite some time ago, and I hope you've found a solution by now, but for the benefit of other readers:

Scikit-learn has a module [grid_search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.grid_search) for parameter sweeping.

[Further documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search)

Comment: Lacks lot of features compared to the lab, but I will accept anyway, I guess this is as close as it gets.